# How to remove the child element of a div in react using useRef hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to remove the old SVG and create a new SVG whenever the chart_data value changes.

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import { useSelector} from "react-redux";

const Barchart = () =>{
    const chart = useRef(null);
    const chart_data= useSelector(state => state.ChartReducer);

    useEffect(() => {
        let svg = d3.select(chart.current)
        //code to create the chart
        //
        return () => {
            //How to remove the old svg element from the ref chart.current?
            //I tried
            chart.current.removeChild() // This throws an error saying expects 1 argument got 0

        }
    },[chart_data])

    return(
       <div className="bar-chart" ref={chart}></div>
    )

}

export default Barchart
```

`chart.current.removeChild()` is not removing the children of `<div className="bar-chart" ref={chart}></div>`

How to remove all the child element of a div which has useRef reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should indicate the child element in the `removeChild()` method.

```
chart.current.removeChild(chart.current.children[0])
```

Comment: This is working. But what if I want to remove all the child elements?

Comment: you should iterate chart.current.children and do the removeChild() each.

Comment: If you want to remove all child elements you can set innerHTML property, chart.current.innerHTML = ""

Answer (score 5):

[Node.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) requires the child node to be removed as argument. If you want to remove all the child element, you can use [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```
chart.current.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Caution: innerHTML removes all child nodes of a node, however, it is not recommended because it doesn’t remove the event handlers of the child nodes, which might cause a memory leak.

Comment: @jfunk I think it remove the event handlers if you try to edit the node with innerHTML, something like this node.innerHTML +='<br/>' would cause memory leak because it removes the event handlers, but this node.innerHTML = "" is safe, please share with me any reference.

Comment: it seems you are correct, regardless of how the elements are removed from the DOM if the event handlers are not removed prior to deletion there is a risk of memory leak -- here is my original source, https://htmldom.dev/remove-all-children-of-a-node

Answer (score 0):

[`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) requires a node argument (the child node to remove) that you're missing.

There's nothing React specific about this problem.

Did you maybe mean

```
chart.current.removeChild(svg)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I used the above answer i.e. *You should indicate the child element in the **removeChild()** method*. But It throws an error and I handle it this way:

```js
if (chart.current.children[0]) {
  chart.current.removeChild(chart.current.children[0]);
}
```

So it checks for the child if it is present then it will remove it.