# Unable to remove child from useRef hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following `useRef` which contains 4 children.

I am trying to remove a child from here based on an if check.

But getting the error:

```
typeError: myRef.current.removeChild is not a function.
```

But looking at the answers here this seems to be correct. What am I doing wrong?

[How to remove the child element of a div in react using useRef hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425206/how-to-remove-the-child-element-of-a-div-in-react-using-useref-hook)

```
//This is coming from another file. Just for reference. 
const myRef = React.useRef();

export const postData = (
  myRef,
  token,
  id1,
  id2,
) => {
  myRef.current.children[0].value = token;
  myRef.current.children[1].value = id1;
  myRef.current.children[2].value = id2;

  [...myRef.current.children].forEach((child) => {
    if (!child.value) {

      // error on this line 
      myRef.current.removeChild(child);
      
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `useEffect` hook in here, maybe this will solve your issue.

```js
...
const myRef = useRef(null)
useEffect(() => {
  myRef.current.children[0].value = token;
  myRef.current.children[1].value = id1;
  myRef.current.children[2].value = id2;

  [...myRef.current.children].forEach((child) => {
    if (!child.value) {
      myRef.current.removeChild(child);

    }
  });
}, [myRef.current, child.value])

return (
  <div ref={myRef}>
    ...
  </div>
)
...
```

Comment: I would also suggest adding `myRef.current` and `child.value` to this useEffect's dependency array.

Comment: yes, you're correct, changed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but not looking to call this inside useEffect.